# ViewPager adaper - call "setCurrentItem()" from within Adapter

Tags: android-viewpager, adapter

Is there any way to call `setCurrentItem()` for ViewPager Adapter from within that Adapter? I can't call it from outside.

Long version now. I have a stack of cards (like Tinder) that is created with RecyclerView adapter. But then each card has a ViewPager with one or more images - so it's like an Adapter within the Adapter.

Now, the first card is always on top and I see the first image on that card. When I tap on the right side of that image, it needs to be scrolled to the next image.

I've already detected the tap within the Viewpager item ... BUT... to make it scroll it seems like I have to call `viewPagerAdapter.setCurrentItem(1)` from outside the Viewpager - and when I do it that way, then it scrolls to the second image in each Viewpager adapter in every Card - but I need it to happen only within the first card and the first Viewpager adapter.

Comment: Can you explain in the question exactly what you are trying to do? Maybe there is a better way to call the method from the ViewPager's parent activity/fragment!

Comment: Hey Ali. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Try calling the method from the fragment/ activity that hosts the ViewPager.

Comment: Once again, the activity doesn't hold a ViewPager. Recyclerview holds the ViewPager.

Comment: Add this "RecyclerView" class to the question.